# Row updating a Row in the same table with a condition

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Lets say I have some dupe rows in a table, and I want to save whatever information that was saved in the dupe rows to be saved on the proper row if that field is empty or null in the proper row, otherwise do nothing.

For example before:

```
ID   NAME   EMAIL         VALUE
1    NULL                 1000
2    Sam    asd@asd.com   0550
```

After:

```
ID   NAME   EMAIL         VALUE
1    Sam    asd@asd.com   1000
2    Sam    asd@asd.com   0550
```

```
UPDATE Real
SET Real.A = Dupe.A
FROM Table1 Real, Table1 Dupe
where ((Real.id = @Rea_ID and Dupe.ID = @Dup_ID) and ((Real.A is null or Real.A = '')))

UPDATE Real
SET Real.B = Dupe.B
FROM Table1 Real, Table1 Dupe
where ((Real.id = @Rea_ID and Dupe.ID = @Dup_ID) and ((Real.B is null or Real.B = '')))

.
.
.
```

And so on for each field in Table1.

This works, but is there a better way?

Comment: Does "Dupe"  mean "duplicated"? If so, how do you identify a record to be duplicated? in your example the two records have nothing in common, how do you know they are repeted?

Comment: Please hover your mouse pointer over the SQL tag you added and read the description of that tag. It recommends that when asking an SQL question, you also add a tag for the specific DBMS you're using, as syntax and functionality varies considerably between them. Please [edit] your question to add that tag. Thanks.

Comment: Ken, added the tag, sorry. Mundo, the dupe and the proper rows are arbitrary, I receive two IDs, the first being the proper one and the second one being the "dupe"  and I have to fill any empty or null values in the proper one with any valid values found in the dupe.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to update all the fields at once, you can just list them all in the update statement like this:

```
UPDATE Real
SET Real.A = Dupe.A
,   Real.B = Dupe.B
,   Real.C = Dupe.C
-- , etc for as many fields as you wish
FROM ...
```

You also mentioned updating only "if that field is empty or null", in which case you can use the isnull function, which will keep the existing value if there is one, but replace it with the new value if it is NULL. You can pair this with the nullif function to turn blank values into NULLs like this:

```
UPDATE Real
SET Real.A = isnull(nullif(Real.A,''),Dupe.A)
,   Real.B = isnull(nullif(Real.B,''),Dupe.B)
,   Real.C = isnull(nullif(Real.C,''),Dupe.C)
-- , etc for as many fields as you wish
FROM Table1 Real, Table1 Dupe
where ((Real.id = @Rea_ID and Dupe.ID = @Dup_ID)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer James! I'm looking for a way to make the answer more compact, like you showed, but the condition ((Real.A is null or Real.A = ''))) has to change with each different field. It's not always Real.A.

Comment: Hi @hopeless123 - I've updated my answer to remove that part of the FROM clause - from my understanding of what you want to do, you don't need it any more once you implement the ISNULL parts.
The ISNULL function used in this way will ONLY update the field if it is NULL (or blank being converted to NULL by the NULLIF function).
That is to say, the record will remain the same if it already has complete fields, just as though it were excluded from the update using a FROM clause.

Comment: HI @hopeless123 - please remember to accept one of the answers once you are happy with them, so that other people can find the answer easily if they come across your question. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using `case` expressions:

```
UPDATE Real
    SET Real.A = (CASE WHEN Real.A IS NULL OR Real.A = '' THEN Dupe.A ELSE Real.A END),
        Real.B = (CASE WHEN Real.B IS NULL OR Real.B = '' THEN Dupe.B ELSE Real.B END),
        Real.C = (CASE WHEN Real.C IS NULL OR Real.C = '' THEN Dupe.C ELSE Real.C END)        
FROM Table1 Real JOIN
     Table1 Dupe
     ON Real.id = @Rea_ID AND Dupe.ID = @Dup_ID
```